# Accessing Container view controller from another Container view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a parent view controller and two containers in it like this:

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyCombinationsViewController *myComb = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyCombinationsViewControllerID"];
myComb.view.frame = self.combinationsContainer.bounds;
[self.combinationsContainer addSubview:myComb.view];
[self addChildViewController:myComb];
[myComb didMoveToParentViewController:self];

StatInfoViewController *stat = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StatInfoViewControllerID"];
stat.view.frame = self.statContainer.bounds;
[self.statContainer addSubview:stat.view];
[self addChildViewController:stat];
[stat didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I want to do something inside`StatInfoViewController` that effects `MyCombinationsViewController`. How can I access MyCombinationsViewController properties without reallocating it?

Doing this:

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyCombinationsViewController *myComb = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyCombinationsViewControllerID"];
```

inside `StatInfoViewController` returns empty properties when I try to do something like `NSLog(@"%@",myComb.something);`

Comment: Use NSNotificationCenter if both container aren't in relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You could link them togehter, by in the headers of StatInfoViewController add:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) MyCombinationsViewController* myCombinationsViewController
```

And then when allocating them do the following:

```
StatInfoViewController *stat = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StatInfoViewControllerID"];
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyCombinationsViewController *myComb = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyCombinationsViewControllerID"];

stat.myCombinationsViewController = myComb;


myComb.view.frame = self.combinationsContainer.bounds;
[self.combinationsContainer addSubview:myComb.view];
[self addChildViewController:myComb];
[myComb didMoveToParentViewController:self];

stat.view.frame = self.statContainer.bounds;
[self.statContainer addSubview:stat.view];
[self addChildViewController:stat];
[stat didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Then you can access myCombinationsViewController from inside StatInfoViewController